# How to create an editable treeview using MUI?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui, mui-x

How to create How to create an editable treeview using MUI in React Typescript?
for example in this tree view:

[image]

I created that treeview using MUI. I want every node to be editable and when I click to edit that node won't collapse or expand